# IE conditional comments only working on certain pages

Tags: css, internet-explorer

im using this conditional comment for styles for ie 6-8.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/ie6-8.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

and im testing it with browserstack.com.
it works fine on my first 2 pages but no style at all are adopted on my second two pages yet the comment is exactly the same.(i copied it). my website is http://www.championcleaners.co.uk if you want to have a look in the ie 6-8 browsers.
any help would be much appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this it is a better solution

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

it will add classes to your HTML depensing on browser then you can target any element like in example below:

```
.ie6 .class-name { 
    border:1px solid red;
}
.ie7 .class-name { 
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```